# Entity Framework Core 2.1 trouble with relationships

Tags: sql, ef-core-2.1

I'm trying to convert the following sql query to entity framework but running into problems with what appears columns not joining to tables.

```
SELECT 
a.TABLE_NAME AS tableName,
b.COLUMN_NAME AS columnName,
b.DATA_TYPE AS dataType,
CASE WHEN b.IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END AS allowNull
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES a
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS b ON a.TABLE_NAME = b.TABLE_NAME
```

This is what i have so far

DB Context:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EFCoreTest.Models 
{
    public class InformationContext : DbContext
    {   
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) 
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=localhost;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Table>()
                .HasKey(t => new {t.tableName, t.catalogName, t.schemaName});

            modelBuilder.Entity<Column>()
                .HasOne(c => c.table)
                .WithMany(c => c.columns)
                .HasForeignKey(c => new {c.tableName, c.catalogName, c.schemaName});

        }

        public DbSet<Table> Tables {get; set;}
        public DbSet<Column> Columns {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Column Class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace EFCoreTest.Models
{
    [Table("COLUMNS", Schema = "INFORMATION_SCHEMA")]
    public class Column
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("COLUMN_NAME")]
        public String columnName {get; set;}
        [Column("DATA_TYPE")]
        public String dataType {get; set;}
        [Column("IS_NULLABLE")]
        public String allowNUlls {get; set;}
        [ForeignKey("Table")]
        [Column("TABLE_NAME")]
        public String tableName {get; set;}
        [ForeignKey("Table")]
        [Column("TABLE_CATALOG")]
        public String catalogName {get; set;}
        [ForeignKey("Table")]
        [Column("TABLE_SCHEMA")]
        public String schemaName {get; set;}
        public Table table {get; set;}

    }
}
```

Table class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace EFCoreTest.Models
{
    [Table("TABLES" , Schema = "INFORMATION_SCHEMA")]
    public class Table
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("TABLE_NAME")]
        public String tableName {get; set;}
        [Key]
        [Column("TABLE_CATALOG")]
        public String catalogName {get; set;}
        [Key]
        [Column("TABLE_SCHEMA")]
        public String schemaName {get; set;}
        public ICollection<Column> columns {get; set;}

        protected Table() {columns = new List<Column>();}
    }
}
```

Main:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;
using EFCoreTest.Models;

namespace EFCoreTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using(InformationContext context = new InformationContext())
            {
                var results = context.Tables.Include(t => t.columns).ToList();

                foreach(var t in results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(t.tableName);
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");
                    var columns = t.columns.ToList();

                    foreach(var c in columns)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(c.columnName);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code runs fine, but when inspecting the table instances all the column instances are null. I have a feeling it has something to do with the relationship between table and column but after going over the docs for relationships for efcore2.1 i cant work out what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**
Updated code with additional keys and related data loading.

Comment: Everything is fine with your entity model, [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) section of the EF Core documentation will give you the idea for different methods of retrieving the related data (by default it's not retrieved).

Comment: aside to your problem, your keys are too simple and result in columns of the same name to be fetched only once, for the first entity that uses it. Your keys should include catalog_name and schema_name as well!

Comment: So should i add those two in both table and column model?

Comment: I've updated the code with the new keys on table and column. Columns are still only being fetched once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
context.Tables.Include(t => t.columns).ToList();
```

Comment: Properties are by default lazy loaded unless specified explicitly in the context which is not the case here. The minus is not from me though ;) PS - here a plus to balance

Comment: @PiotrJerzyMamenas Nothing is lazy loaded by default in EF Core.

Comment: @IvanStoev I just double checked and you are of course right, in EF6 its by default lazy loaded which is not the case for the lighter Core, I always disable lazy loading globally because of the known serialization issues so I always use includes instead of virtual props or global lazy loading anyway so I was not even aware its different.

Comment: Thank you,  changing this did start populating columns in tables.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, welcome to stack overflow.

As per the answer from Gonzalo, the Include statement will let you include a collection:

```
context.Tables.Include(t => t.columns).ToList();
```

I would like to however highlight a few other minor improvements you could do to make your code more robust and maintainable as the time goes.

1. Remember to initialize your entities with a protected constructor to avoid null pointer exceptions, as in most cases returning empty collections with an entity should be a valid scenario for business apps:

   protected Table()
   {
       columns = new List();
   }
2. Use ICollection for collection definition instead of List.
3. The common naming standards in C# is using Pascal casing when declaring public properties and collections.
4. You are mixing 2 different ways of defining relationships.

This:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Column>()
    .HasOne(c => c.table)
    .WithMany(c => c.columns)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.tableForeignKey);
```

and the annotations that you use on the relevant properties of the entities like [Key] are actually two different ways to do the same thing. Use one, preferably the code first i.e through configurations.

5, I would suggest using separate entity type configuration file, otherwise your schema will eventually be very difficult to maintain, example base configuration:

```
public class BaseEntityConfiguration<TEntity> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
    where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(be => be.Guid);

        builder.Property(be => be.CreatedBy).IsRequired();

        builder.Property(be => be.CreatedDate).IsRequired();
    }
}

public class AddressConfiguration : BaseEntityConfiguration<Address>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Address> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(a => a.Contact)
            .WithMany(c => c.Addresses)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.ContactGuid);

        builder.HasOne(a => a.Partner)
            .WithMany(a => a.Addresses)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.PartnerGuid);

        base.Configure(builder);
    }
}
```

and in the context:

```
modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new AddressConfiguration());
```

As you probably noticed I also use BaseEntity to hold all the repeating properties like Id and just derive all my entities from it. I would suggest you do the same.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, regarding mixing relationship methods i removed foreign key and primary key annotation but when running the code it required that i assign a  primary key to both table and column. When i did this it worked but looks like it isn't loading columns where they are already present in other tables. Would this be because setting column names as primary key is not a good idea since the same column names could be present in the database?

Comment: As you can see from the example I am using a guid as a key in a BaseEntity class so all entities have a unique key, this can also just be an integer, both guid and integer indexing have their pluses and minuses. You are right and should definitely not use name strings for indexing. I would remove the triple composite key and replace it with a simple id on columns (table should also have an id) and join them together through these id's. I am guessing your issue might also come from lack of property name specification [Column("TABLE_SCHEMA")] which you now should point through configuration.

Comment: @ReganFrank On top of what I wrote above, it not a completely inherently bad practice to use strings for keys, as you can do composite keys if you want to ensure you don't for example have 2 same name tables in the database, plus it improves database indexing but in this case I would just add an Id to column and table and link them together via Id. You can also add a navigation property to column for the Id like "TableId" and specify it in the foreign key mapping in the configuration.

Comment: The tables i am mapping to on the database are sys tables / schema so i cant change them but do you mean i can add my own id to the entity?

Comment: @ReganFrank if these are sys tables on the database that you are trying to map, then, likely they already have an Id property. If not then you can alternatively wrap it around in a view and expose the view instead via mapping (just use the view name instead of table name). Just make sure to use some decent naming standard to make sure other developers are aware this is a view as this is not always obvious without checking. P.S - remember to tag Gonzalo's response as answer.